# ASP.NET Web.config URL Rewrite Regex

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I'm trying to clean up some requests that are coming in to be returning 404 rather than a 200.

For example someone has links to my site like this:

```
http://example.com/?publisher=123456
```

I am trying to add a rewrite rule to handle this case like this:

```
    <rule name="Redirect publisher" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)\/\?publisher=(.*)$" negate="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false"></conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="Not Found" statusDescription="The requested URL was not found." />
    </rule>
```

I followed the [Microsoft instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference), however, even though [my test](https://regex101.com/r/mforhY/1/) shows that the above regex should work, nothing happens. I tried doing a more common redirect, like this:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

However, yet again nothing happens. It's like my regex is bad or something?

Answer (score 0):

I finally did figure it out:

```
    <rule name="Redirect publisher" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="publisher" negate="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="Not Found" statusDescription="The requested URL was not found." />
    </rule>
```